# How can I solve atmega328p-pu resetting while it is supplied from power supply

Tags: atmega

Currently I am using a dip Atmega328p-pu with a breadboard built circuit. The problem is when i am supplying the circuit from Arduino Uno's 5V it is working perfectly fine, but it's not working when I supply it from power supply. When I mean not working, it has the typical blink code in it and it works perfectly fine with uno's 5v, but it keeps resetting or freezing in one part of code -the led just lights instead of blinking-

The circuit has 10k resistor in first pin, 16 mhz crystal, 2x22 pf capacitors near it and all power connections are also connected

Thank you

Comment: You should try this question at [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). My 2 cents: 16MHz is an awfully high frequency for a breadboard. Good luck with that.

Comment: [Reconfigure it to use the internal oscillator](http://waihung.net/using-internal-oscillator-on-atmega328p/), so you don't have flaky/unstable excessive frequency circuit on the breadboard. Once you have debugged and finished the design, and you use a proper PCB, the crystal would be fine.